# Classification of simple modules for the free algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, computability-theory

Let $A=K\langle x,y\rangle$ be the free associative algebra in two generators over a field $K$ (we can assume  that the field is algebraically closed or even $K=\mathbb{C}$ first if that helps)

> Question: Is there a classification of finite dimensional **simple** $A$-modules or can one show that this is "impossible" as in the word problem for groups?

Comment: I believe that is an example of what's called a "wild" problem, and so considered unsolvable. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43280/reference-for-a-wild-problem

Comment: @Chris I agree that it looks like a wild problem but it might be difficult to make this precise since the Hom spaces are rather trivial (compared to the well known wild problem to classify the indecomposables of that algebra).

Comment: This is the same as classifying pairs of matrices up to simultaneous conjugation.

Comment: @YCor But it is about simple modules and not about indecomposable modules (which would make the problem directly equivalent to classify all representations).

Comment: Indeed, this is correct. Anyway, when the ground field is alg. closed, there is a simple algorithm to check whether a given module is simple (i.e., check whether the two matrices generate the matrix algebra as an algebra).

Comment: @Mare One would assume that if a pair of matrices is generic the corresponding module is simple, so the two questions are not that far away?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why people say that encoding the word problem for groups into the first order theory for modules means classification is impossible. I find this a misunderstanding.  Also it is not obviously true you can encode the word problem for groups in finite dimensional modules.  But you can encode the uniform word problem for finite groups and so at least over characteristic 0 you can encode an undecidable result in the first order theory of semisimple modules.

Comment: See my old blog post https://bensteinberg.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/the-first-order-theory-of-two-endomorphisms-of-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-undecidable/#more-232 but you need to use the group theoretic version not the semigroup version of the undecidable problem

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended version of my comments.   For more details one should look at my very old [blogpost](https://bensteinberg.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/the-first-order-theory-of-two-endomorphisms-of-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-is-undecidable/#more-232) at my now discontinued blog.

Very roughly, a $K$-algebra $A$ is of wild representation type if classifying the finite dimensional indecomposable representations of $A$ is as hard as classifying the finite dimensional indecomposable representation of any $K$-algebra.  There is a precise technical definition of what this means.

A commonly given explanation as to why wild classification problems are hard is that one can encode the word problem for groups into the first order theory of the module category of wild algebra.    Prest has proved more precise statements of this sort.  To be honest, this doesn't seem all that related to me to the difficulty of the classification problem and so I'm not sure why people always bring it up in this context.

It's pretty clear what is the first order theory of two automorphisms of a vector space over a field.   You can talk about the two automorphisms, vectors, scalar multiplication and addition.  Now if one wants to work with infinite dimensional vector spaces, then it is easy to encode the word problem for groups into the first order theory.  Just take a finite presentation of a group $G$ with $2$-generators with undecidable word problem.  To test if $w=1$ in this group you write a sentence saying that if the finitely many relations defining $G$ are satisfied by the automorphisms, then subbing the automorphisms into $w$ gives you the identity map.    By considering the regular representation of $G$, we see that this sentence is true iff $w=1$ in the group $G$.

The problem is that this uses an infinite dimensional vector space because $G$ is an infinite group. So this is totally irrelevant to the question of finite dimensional representations.   But there is a beautiful result of Slobodoskoi that says that the uniform word problem for finite groups is undecidable.  What this means is given a finite set of generators $X$ and relations $R$, it is undecidable given a word $w$ if the image of $w$ is $1$ under all homomorphisms from the free group on $X$ to a finite group such that the words in $R$ map to $1$.   A theorem of Mal'cev says that any finitely generated group of matrices over a field is residually finite and hence it is also undecidable whether $w$ maps to $1$ under all finite dimensional representations of the free group on $X$ over the field $K$ for which $R$ maps to $1$.  This question can then be rephrased like above in the first order theory of two automorphisms  (and hence of two endomorphisms) by first embedding the free group on $X$ into the two generated free group.

Now if $K$ is of characteristic $0$, then since finite group has semisimple algebras, it follows that $w=1$ is a consequence of $R$ in all finite groups iff it is consequence of $R$ under all irreducible representations of the free group on $X$.  So at least in characteristic $0$ this problem can be encoded into the first order theory of irreducible representations of the free algebra.